# how do i solve issue with local storage and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a sign up with relevant functions to save a user data as they sign up. I don't seem to get what the issue is but the data isn't saving to the local storage. I should be working well but I can't figure out what the problem is.

the javascript file does the following
1) handles cases where someone is duplicating data with the email
2) saving an object to the local storage which is passed into an array

```js
var signUpBtn = document.querySelector('#signUp');
var signUpOver = document.querySelector('.signup__overlay');

var signInBtn = document.querySelector('#signIn');
var signInOver = document.querySelector('.signin__overlay');

var fullname = document.querySelector('#name');
var email = document.querySelector('#email');
var password = document.querySelector('#password');
var age = document.querySelector('#age');
var occupation = document.querySelector('#occupation');
var Address = document.querySelector('#address');

var signupSubmitClicked = document.querySelector('#signupClicked'); 

signupSubmitClicked.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fullname.value=="" || email.value=="" || password.value=="" || age.value=="" || occupation.value=="" || Address.value=="") {
    alert("incomplete datails, please fill up everything")
  } else {
    alert("item created")
    addUser(fullname, email, password, age,  occupation, Address);
  }
});

var fetchUsers = () => {
  try {
      var userString = localStorage.getItem('userData');
      return JSON.parse(userString);            
  } catch (error) {
      return [];
  }
};

var saveUser = (users) => {
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(users));
};

var addUser = (fullname, email, password, age,  occupation, Address) => {
  var users = fetchUsers();
  var user = {
      fullname,
      email,
      password,
      age,
      occupation,
      Address
  };

  var duplicateUsers = users.filter(user => user.email === email);

  if (duplicateUsers.length === 0) {
      users.push(user);
      saveUser(users);
      return user;
  }
};

/*************
signup popup
*************/
signUpBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  signUpOver.style.display = 'block';
});

signUpOver.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(event.target == signUpOver){
    signUpOver.style.display = "none";
  }
});
/*************
signup popup
*************/

/*************
signin popup
*************/
signInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  signInOver.style.display = 'block';
});

signInOver.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(event.target == signInOver){
    signInOver.style.display = "none";
  }
});
/*************
signin popup
*************/
/** the end */
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F8F9F9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#mainPage,
#userPage {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#userPage {
  display: none;
}

/********************
overlay
********************/
.signup__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.signup__content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.signin__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.signin__content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}


/********************
overlay ending
********************/

.headerMain {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.headerUser {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.upButton {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upButton, .inButton {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: #239B56;
  border: #239B56;
  color: snow;
}

label {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

label,
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>User system</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="mainPage">

      <div class="signup__overlay">
        <div class="signup__content">
          <form>
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="name">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input required type="text" id="email" name="email">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input required type="password" id="password" name="password">

            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input required type="text" id="age" name="age">

            <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
            <input required type="text" id="occupation" name="occupation">

            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input required type="text" id="address" name="address">

            <input type="submit" id="signupClicked">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="signin__overlay">
        <div class="signin__content">
          <form>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input required type="text" id="Email" name="email">

            <label for="email">Password</label>
            <input required type="Password" id="Password" name="Password">

            <input type="submit" id="signinClicked">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>


    <header class="headerMain">User System</header>
    <section>
        <button class="upButton" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>

        <button class="inButton" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div id="userPage">

      <header class="headerUser">User System</header>
      <section>
          
      </section>
  
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing is you do not cancel the click action of the form.

Comment: You’re not handling the case when your LocalStorage entry is empty at the beginning and it returns `null`. Try `return JSON.parse(userString) || [];` in the `try` block in `fetchUsers` instead of `return JSON.parse(userString);`.

Comment: @Xufox He does that with `try/catch` around `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Barmar why would JSON.parse(null) throw an error?

Comment: @Barmar No…? `fetchUsers` returns `null` when `localStorage.getItem('userData')` is `null`.

Comment: Yeah, it probably should, but I just tested and it doesn't.

Comment: @Xufox Sounds like an answer you should post.

Comment: If it returned undefined it would throw the error. difference between `localStorage["aaaa"]` and `localStorage.getItem("aaaa")` drives me nuts. :)

Comment: @Xufox your solution solved the problem for me. thanks a lot. I think you should post the answer so I can mark as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not handling the case when your `LocalStorage` entry is empty at the beginning where it returns `null`. `JSON.parse(null);` is just `null`, so `fetchUsers` returns `null`, but then you proceed with

```
var users = fetchUsers();
// …
var duplicateUsers = users.filter(user => user.email === email);
```

which should result in `TypeError: users is null`, if you open the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>) and read this error.

Instead, default to `[]` like this:

```
var fetchUsers = () => {
  try {
      var userString = localStorage.getItem('userData');
      return JSON.parse(userString) || [];
  } catch (error) {
      return [];
  }
};
```

---

Other things:

- As [pointed out by epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683345/how-do-i-solve-issue-with-local-storage-and-javascript#comment86378351_49683345), you should prevent the submit when the form isn’t completely filled. You may want to prevent the default unconditionally and submit the form programatically, depending on your needs:

```js
signupSubmitClicked.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (fullname.value=="" || email.value=="" || password.value=="" || age.value=="" || occupation.value=="" || Address.value=="") {
    alert("incomplete datails, please fill up everything");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    alert("item created");
    addUser(fullname, email, password, age, occupation, Address);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

See MDN documentation [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Note you must strinigify any objects prior to storing them to localstorage with `JSON.stringify` then you can parse them back to an object when you read them back.

> localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');